# Keyboard not being shown correctly

Tags: swift, keyboard

I have got the following functions that make the keyboard not to cover the TextView, but the keyboard is not showing correctly. Instead, there appears a kind of all black "keyboard" with no keyboard keys.

```
func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
    moveTextView(textView, moveDistance: -250, up: true)
}

func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
    moveTextView(textView, moveDistance: -250, up: false)
}

func textViewShouldReturn(_ textView: UITextView) -> Bool {
    textView.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}

func moveTextView(_ textView: UITextView, moveDistance: Int, up: Bool) {
    let moveDuration = 0.3
    let movement: CGFloat = CGFloat(up ? moveDistance : -moveDistance)

    UIView.beginAnimations("animateTextView", context: nil)
    UIView.setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState(true)
    UIView.setAnimationDuration(moveDuration)
    self.view.frame = self.view.frame.offsetBy(dx: 0, dy: movement)
    UIView.commitAnimations()
}
```

Do somebody have an idea of why and how to fix it?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do it another way. Add `UITextViewDelegate` to your viewController. Add smth like this in viewDidLoad():

```
self.yourTextView1.delegate = self
self.yourTextView2.delegate = self

//For scrolling the view if keyboard on
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(YourViewController.keyboardWillShow), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(YourViewController.keyboardWillHide), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
```

And add this to your ViewController:

```
var keyBoardAlreadyShowed = false //using this to not let app to scroll view
//if we tapped UITextField and then another UITextField
func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    if !keyBoardAlreadyShowed {
        self.view.frame.origin.y -= 50 // we will scroll on it
        keyBoardAlreadyShowed = true
    }
}

func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    self.view.frame.origin.y += 50
    keyBoardAlreadyShowed = false
}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment. Why `UITextFieldDelegate` instead of `UITextViewDelegate`?

Comment: @alberzyzz Yeah. Sorry. If u r using textView use UITextViewDelegate

Comment: Keyboard is not being shown and the view is creating a black space at the top of it, increasing every time I click the textView

Comment: @alberzyzz I'm pretty sure, that you are testing on simulator, isn't it?. Configure it to show keyboard or test on iphone.

Comment: Yep, it was this! Thank you again.

Comment: @alberzyzz glad to hear:)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

iOS Simulator > Restore Content and Settings.

Clean the Project, and restart Xcode.